# Unmarshal list to LinkedList Jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

How I can specify collection implementation when unmarshalling list. For some list of entities I prefer to use LinkedList, but jaxb makes ArrayList for appropriate elements. Is there simplest way to point collection Impl for List<>?

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "column")
    public class Column {

    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    public List<Property> properties;

    @XmlElement(name = "list-property")
    public List<ListProperty> listProperties;
}
```

.

```
        <column>
            <list-property name="a">...</list-property>
            <list-property name="b">...</list-property>
            <property name="width">10</property>
            <property name="height">20</property>
        </column>
```

.

```
    public Column getObject(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Column.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return (Column) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    } catch (JAXBException jex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Object parse was fail", jex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jaxb should generate a list of the form `List<JAXBElement<X>>` so you can work with any implementation. If this is not your case, can you add some code example where jaxb is generating an arrayList?

Comment: I have updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `listProperties` as a linked list :

```
@XmlElement(name = "list-property")
public List<ListProperty> listProperties = new LinkedList<ListProperty>();
```

then unmarshaller will return it as linked list.

Comment: Then empty lists will always be initialized when each object is created. Your solution works. But maybe there is some elegant solution to avoid this behavior?